# Django field to select range between two values?

Tags: python, django, django-models, slider

How do I implement a range selector with Django models?

What I want to accomplish is a to select data from a predefined list (normal list, not the Python one),

1. poor
2. below average
3. average
4. above average
5. good
6. average.

while adding a student,

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    class = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    grade = ?
```

The poor is the base value, I want is to add a range selection, when a student is added with value `good`, he must get all the values from `poor` to `good`, while a student added as `average` just gets the value `poor` to `average`.

a practical example be a [slider](http://www.getmdl.io/components/index.html#sliders-section),

Is there a field that can get this done?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Check out some examples at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#choices

In your case it would be something like:

```
CHOICES = (
    (1, 'poor'),
    (2, 'below average'),
    (3, 'average'),
    (4, 'above average'),
    (5, 'good'),
    (6, 'average')
)

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    class = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    grade = models.IntegerField(choices=CHOICES)
```

I'm not sure if I get your code right, but this should give you an idea.